# Can I have H2 autocreate a schema in an in-memory database?

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

(I've already seen the [H2 database In memory - Init schema via Spring/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945175/h2-database-in-memory-init-schema-via-spring-hibernate) question; it is not applicable here.)

I'd like to know if there's a setting in H2 that will allow me to auto-create a schema upon connecting to it.  If it helps, I'm only interested in the in-memory case.

H2 supports various semicolon-separated modifiers at the end of the URL, but I didn't find one for automatically creating a schema.  Is there such a feature?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Yes, H2 supports [executing SQL statements when connecting](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection). You could run a script, or just a statement or two:

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;" + 
             "INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST"
String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;" + 
             "INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST\\;" + 
                  "SET SCHEMA TEST";
String url = "jdbc:h2:mem;" + 
             "INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/create.sql'\\;" + 
                  "RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/populate.sql'";
```

Please note the double backslash (`\\`) is only required within Java. The backslash(es) before `;` within the `INIT` is required.

Comment: Thank you very much; not sure how I missed that in the (excellent) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, it made the work as I was using generated changesets from liquibase that use the schema name for generated xml.

Comment: Note that if you use H2 with hibernate and want to run multiple scripts by calling **RUNSCRIPT**, you should type triple backslash (\\\\). For example, you should set up `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'script1.sql'\\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM script2.sql'</property>` in your hibernate config.

Comment: @Johnny Are you sure? It looks like the `;` doesn't need to be escaped (there is an unescaped `;` before the `INIT`). Could you try if using only one backslash works? `'script1.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT...`

Comment: You are right, @Thomas. It works. But with triple slash it also works fine.

Comment: is it possible to fetch script from classpath file?

Comment: @pinkpanther yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490138/problem-with-init-runscript-and-relative-paths

Answer (score 34):

If you are using spring with `application.yml`, the following will work for you:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS calendar
```

Comment: It is also possible to create a schema this way in Grails 3

Comment: And if you want to set schema as well:
`INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS calendar\;SET SCHEMA calendar`

Answer (score 11):

What Thomas has written is correct, in addition to that, if you want to initialize multiple schemas you can use the following. Note there is a `\\;` separating the two create statements.

```
    EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                    .setName("testDb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;INIT=create " +
                            "schema if not exists " +
                            "schema_a\\;create schema if not exists schema_b;" +
                            "DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;")
                    .addScript("sql/provPlan/createTable.sql")
                    .addScript("sql/provPlan/insertData.sql")
                    .addScript("sql/provPlan/insertSpecRel.sql")
                    .build();
```

ref : http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection

Answer (score 8):

"By default, when an application calls `DriverManager.getConnection(url, ...)` and the database specified in the URL does not yet exist, a new (empty) database is created."—[H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists).

Addendum: @Thomas Mueller shows how to [*Execute SQL on Connection*](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection), but I sometimes just create and populate in the code, as suggested below.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225700 */
public class H2MemTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("create table customer(id integer, name varchar(10))");
        st.execute("insert into customer values (1, 'Thomas')");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select name from customer");
        while (rset.next()) {
            String name = rset.getString(1);
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and that is the *catalog* or *database*, not a schema within it.  So you might open a connection to jdbc:h2:mem:test, for example, but by default you are placed in the PUBLIC schema, and no other schemata exist.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Spring Framework with `application.yml` and having trouble to make the test find the SQL file on the `INIT` property, you can use the `classpath:` notation.

For example, if you have a `init.sql` SQL file on the `src/test/resources`, [just use](https://cinhtau.net/2015/10/29/excecute-sql-on-connection-with-h2/):

```
url=jdbc:h2:~/test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring and xml configuration, here is an example how this should be done:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" depends-on="h2Server">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
<property name="url"
          value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/create_tables.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/insert.sql';TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=3;"/>
<property name="username" value="sa"/>
<property name="password" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that causes confusing message! I had been added

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

to the configuration for handling keyword names. but it keeps saying category `"menu"` does not exists.
I tried to verify if INIT script is running by tampring it to something wrong, and h2 causes an error (which is a true behaviour).
So I was sure that `menu` schema will be generated.

Finally I found that h2 database says `"menu"` schema does not exists not `menu` schema!

Then I removed globally_quoted_identifiers and everything goes fine!