# Play Framework: How do I change the sort order of my database?

Tags: playframework, h2

I have a Play app with db=mem in my application.conf file, and I want to be able to set the database's collation to French, with strength set to primary. Any idea how to do this?

If I add

```
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;
```

to my application.conf file, it runs, but using the wrong collation. If I change it to

```
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;COLLATION=FRENCH;
```

as per instructions here: [h2 Changing Other Settings when Opening a Connection](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#other_settings). It breaks, giving the following error:

> A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, URL
>   format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName |
>   {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]"
>   but is "jdbc:h2:mem:play" [90046-149]

So it looks like COLLATION isn't a supported parameter.

What is the proper way to set the db sort order in Play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I got it working thanks to this question: [Can I have H2 autocreate a schema in an in-memory database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225700/can-i-have-h2-autocreate-a-schema-in-an-in-memory-database#answer-5228564).

The line that works for me is

```
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;INIT=SET COLLATION FRENCH STRENGTH PRIMARY
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the trailing semicolon (the one at the very end). This works:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:play;COLLATION=FRENCH
```

this doesnt:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:play;COLLATION=FRENCH;
```