# Schema related problems with Flyway / Spring and H2 embedded database

Tags: spring, h2, flyway

I am building a Spring 3 MVC app that uses a MySQL database and have recently integrated Flyway into the solution to manage the database migrations. I have successfully configured my applicationContext.xml according to the [Flyway documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api.html) such that, upon application startup, Flyway will migrate to the latest version.

I am having trouble getting Flyway to play nicely with my unit / functional tests. I am using Spring Data JPA for my data access layer and have built some JUnit tests to test some custom queries.

The application config I use for these tests is:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:medical_claims_tracker;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS medical_claims_tracker" />
</bean>

<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="schemas" value="medical_claims_tracker"/>
    <property name="sqlMigrationPrefix" value="Migration_"/>
</bean>
```

When I run my unit tests (either through Eclipse or using Maven) I get the following exception:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4cd4544] to prepare test instance [name.hines.steven.medical_claims_tracker.repositories.ExpenseRepositoryTest@1664a9b]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [tests_persistence-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error setting current schema to medical_claims_tracker
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [tests_persistence-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error setting current schema to medical_claims_tracker
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error setting current schema to medical_claims_tracker
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1250)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:820)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "medical_claims_tracker" not found; SQL statement:
SET SCHEMA "medical_claims_tracker" [90079-160]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getSchema(Database.java:1501)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Set.update(Set.java:290)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:73)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:181)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:280)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.h2.H2DbSupport.setCurrentSchema(H2DbSupport.java:79)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1247)
    ... 62 more
```

I can't work out how to get the H2 database to recognise the fact that I want to use a schema called medical_claims_tracker. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225700/can-i-have-h2-autocreate-a-schema-in-an-in-memory-database) to help me try out different connection URLs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734410/is-there-a-way-to-run-mysql-in-memory-for-junit-test-cases) to help me nail down the applicationContext overrides for use during testing.

I suspect it is something to do with H2 dropping the schema after initial creation but before the test can be run, but I thought that `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;` would solve that for me. Interestingly, if I remove the specification of the schema in the flyway bean config:

```
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sqlMigrationPrefix" value="Migration_"/>
</bean>
```

I get a different exception:

```
INFO : com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl - Creating Metadata table: "public"."schema_version"
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4bd27069] to prepare test instance [name.hines.steven.medical_claims_tracker.repositories.ExpenseRepositoryTest@64d22462]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [tests_persistence-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE "public"."schema_version" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INT,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [tests_persistence-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE "public"."schema_version" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INT,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Error executing statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE "public"."schema_version" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INT,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlStatement.execute(SqlStatement.java:78)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:94)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl$1.doInTransaction(MetaDataTableImpl.java:124)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl$1.doInTransaction(MetaDataTableImpl.java:121)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:54)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.create(MetaDataTableImpl.java:121)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.createIfNotExists(MetaDataTableImpl.java:134)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:834)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:820)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1259)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:820)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "public" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE "public"."schema_version" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INT,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
) [90079-160]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:613)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:620)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5147)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:3800)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:324)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1119)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:164)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:152)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:296)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlStatement.execute(SqlStatement.java:76)
    ... 71 more
```

So it seems that with the first configuration, Flyway is able to create the schema_version table in the medical_claims_tracker schema but can't then find that schema to run the tests in, whereas in the second version, it can't even find the "default" schema in which to create the schema_version table. Is this correct, or have I got this the wrong way round?

Comment: An alternative to this problem would be to stop Flyway being invoked during unit testing. It would be a shame to not test my migrations but acceptable given that I could have Hibernate auto-generate the schema in H2 from the JPA annotations on the domain object. The trouble is that I'm relatively new to Spring and don't know how to "override" the bean definition in my main applicationConfig.xml with one in the test config that says "switch off Flyway".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The schema name in the init script should be quoted or the one you pass to Flyway put in uppercase.

Comment: Aaarggghh!! Was that it? Thank you! It works. I changed the following line in the application config: `<property name="schemas" value="MEDICAL_CLAIMS_TRACKER"/>`

Answer (score 19):

From http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/DbSettings.html:

> databaseToUpper:
> Database setting DATABASE_TO_UPPER (default: true).
>
> **Database short names are converted to uppercase** for the DATABASE()
> function ...
> **Setting this to "false" is experimental. When set to false, all
> identifier names (table names, column names) are case sensitive**...

the problem is that by default schema names are in UPPERCASE.

### Solution:

add `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false` to database url

Answer (score 12):

From what I've tested the whole problem occurs only while mixing flyway and H2 with MySql compatibility mode on (doesn't occur if MySql mode is of). It is caused by case sensitivity inconsistency:

1. h2 during initialization creates default schema 'PUBLIC' (uppercase!)
2. when flyway tries to get default schema name it gets 'public' (lowercase!)
3. when flyway tries to change current schema to 'public' (lowercase!) error is thrown.
   Even when setting flyway schemas to 'MYSCHEMA', at some point of it migration process it always tries to change to 'public'.

In my currently developed application we use MySql as a main database and H2 for testing. My workaround involves creating 'public' (lowercase!) schema during h2 initialization:

spring datasource configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
 <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:MY_APP;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/migration/test/init_tests.sql';"/>
 <property name="username" value="sa"/>
 <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

init_tests.sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "public";
```

Isn't beautifull but works - hope that helps!

Comment: Looking at the flyway code, it seems it tries to set back the schema to the old name ('public') _after_ the migration is done. Thanks for your workaround, works perfectly. Flyway should add an option to *not* change back to the old schema after migration, then the workaround would not be needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, although I'm not using Spring. I'm adding H2 in-memory DB for tests on top of an existing setup with jOOQ + Flyway + PostgreSQL.

The solution for me was a combination of changes:

1. From @Omid's answer above, add `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`  to the startup URL
2. From @Tom's answer, add the schema creation to an init SQL script: `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;` (I didn't need to use the backticks).
3. Finally in the same script, add a 2nd line of `SET SCHEMA public;` after schema creation.

Note that I wasn't able to add `;SCHEMA=public` to the init URL, because this was throwing an error before the schema was being created. Alternatively:

1. Add `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;` to the startup URL.
2. Then add `SET SCHEMA public;` to your init SQL script.

Comment: Had same issue with the same setup. Adding `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public` to the startup URL solved everything for me though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the identifier `public` in the statement is lower case *and* quoted:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"...(...)
```

It should be either unquoted:

```
CREATE TABLE public...(...)
```

or uppercase:

```
CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"...(...)
```

The reason why H2 returns the lowercase "public" in the database meta data is that the MySQL mode is used in the database URL (`;MODE=MySQL`). So *not* using the MySQL mode might solve the problem.

Comment: Flyway uses whatever value H2 returns for the current schema. I guess H2 should probably return PUBLIC instead of public then?

Comment: OK I see. H2 returns lower case "public" because the mode is MySQL. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Just in case if you want to try [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).**

I'm using MySQL as my prod environment and h2 as my test environment.

Generate jooq codes with: `gradle + liquibase + h2`

Found this can solve the problem:

```java
DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
jooqConfiguration.set(new Settings()
        // make everything to uppercase 
        .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.UPPER)
        // mapping oldSchemaName to newSchemaName
        .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping().withSchemata(
                new MappedSchema()
                        .withInput("input_schema")
                        .withOutput("OUTPUT_SCHEMA"))
        ));
```

Write a profile to apply this in spring for h2. So that mysql configs still fine.

Latest docs here [jooq-3.9: settings-name-style](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/).

Comment: I've used this solution with PostgreSQL in order to fix the problem with public/PUBLIC schema differences and it works fine (just different bean injected for tests).