# H2 Embedded database not picking up properties during test on spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, h2

I am trying to create a test that uses an embedded H2 database. But I have to change the spring.datasource.url, I cannot use the default one that is created by spring boot. (this is because I have to change the mode of the H2 database to MYSQL)

This is my `test class`:

```
@JdbcTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(dataSource);
   }
}
```

This is my `application-test.properties`:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
 spring.datasource.username=dbuser
 spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

My dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
```

The console output:

> Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:bfad6b71-3e2d-4a47-a32d-c76988b3c5f6;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'

I would expect the url to be something like this: `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`, I also want it to pick up the `MODE=MYSQL` setting.

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364935/how-to-add-the-mode-mysql-to-embedded-h2-db-in-spring-boot-1-4-1-for-datajpates), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Boot's `@DataJdbcTest`, `@DataJpaTest` and `@JdbcTest`, through `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` will all end up calling `TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration`, which in turn, by default, will configure an in-memory embedded database instance with an auto generated unique name.

That may give you problems if, e.g. you happen to use an JPA Entity with a `@Table` with a non-blank `catalog` attribute, as H2 requires that catalog name to be the same as its database name.

As Dane Savot said in his answer

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

will solve the problem for that test class, but if you want to solve it globally, add

```
spring.test.database.replace=none
```

to your `src/test/resources/application.properties` or `.yaml`. That property controls `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase.replace`'s behavior.

Comment: it dosn't work for mode=PostgreSQL

Comment: im' using  @SpringBootTest for my test class

Answer (score 10):

You need to tell Spring not to replace the random embedded database name with the following:

> @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=
>   AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)

It should then pick up properties you declared in application.properties.

Please feel free to commend whether or not it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that works for me

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-mysql.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class ExternalDbApplicationTestBase {

}
```

I use this class as a base for all related db integration classes.

Comment: Maybe your config file is not on the classpath?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, but how can I rule that out? I am not very familiar with all that yet