# How can i create the table with jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to add an entity in my mysql database, using a basic Spring boot app.

when executing the test code, The DDL error occured. but I don't know why this happened.

So, I found something to help to this error

1. If reserved word in mysql exist in column's name, this will happened => not applicable
2. If i didn't mark the annotation above column or id => not applicable

this is my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

and this is my entity class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Posts {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    private String author;

    @Builder
    public Posts(String title, String content, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void update(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

And this is the test code

```
@SpringBootTest
public class PostsRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    PostsRepository postsRepository;
    
    @AfterEach  
    public void cleanup() {
        postsRepository.deleteAll();
    }
    @Test
    public void Save_Load() {
        String title = "Title";
        String content = "Content";
        
        postsRepository.save(Posts.builder()
            .title(title)
            .content(content)
            .author("jojoldu@gmail.com")
            .build());
        
        List<Posts> postsList = postsRepository.findAll();
        
        Posts posts = postsList.get(0);
        assertThat(posts.getTitle()).isEqualTo(title);
        assertThat(posts.getContent()).isEqualTo(content);
    }
}
```

Last, this is the error code

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table posts (id bigint not null auto_increment, author varchar(255), content TEXT not null, title varchar(500) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) [hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE POSTS (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255), CONTENT TEXT NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) ENGINE=[*]INNODB"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table posts (id bigint not null auto_increment, author varchar(255), content TEXT not null, title varchar(500) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB [42001-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:4976) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readUniqueIdentifier(Parser.java:4962) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:8387) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6276) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:903) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Check if you find what you want here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821490/spring-boot-2-2-1-h2-failures

Comment: I see from your stack trace that you use h2 database , but you use the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` dialect. I guess this is a root cause of your problem.