# H2 database used as volatile for Spring test: cannot create table

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I'm using Spring 2.7.7.

I have several entities, e.g.

```java
@Table(name = "users")
public class UsersEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "INT(11) UNSIGNED")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(256)")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(256)")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id"))
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<RolesEntity> rolesEntity = new HashSet<>();

}
```

This is the `application.properties` used in tests:

```bash
spring.profiles.active=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

Until Spring 2.6.14 it worked, now I got errors in creation table as following:

```bash
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table users (id INT(11) UNSIGNED not null auto_increment, password VARCHAR(256), username VARCHAR(256), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

and, after some line:

```bash
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table users (id INT[*](11) UNSIGNED not null auto_increment, password VARCHAR(256), username VARCHAR(256), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB"; expected "ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT NULL, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON UPDATE, NOT NULL, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, DEFAULT ON NULL, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, AUTO_INCREMENT, ,, )"; SQL statement:
create table users (id INT(11) UNSIGNED not null auto_increment, password VARCHAR(256), username VARCHAR(256), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB [42001-214]
```

I know the error is new version of H2 that doesn't accept anymore MySql commands, like `INT(11) UNSIGNED`. If I remove it from table definition, tests work.

So, I tried setting in `application.properties` as following:

```bash
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL
# also change capital of MySql
# spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

without luck.

Now, how can I solve, without editing totally the table definition?

### Repository

The repository is here, https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/tree/develop develop branch.

If you clone it and change pom.xml as

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

instead of 2.6.14 you can replicate the error.

One of affected test is `[src/test/java/com/bitbank/repositories/BankAccountTransactionsRepositoryTest.java][1]` but generally are all repositories.

### Changing `application.properties` under `src/test/resources

Following comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/11731987/evgenij-ryazanov

I want to be sure that my application properties, under test, is used.

So, I tried:

1. Edit the BankAccountTransactionsRepository linked above adding `@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`
2. Adding the @TestPropertySource("classpath:application-notexists.properties") and really test crashed (`Failed to load application` and `class path resource [application-notexists.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`)
3. Renamed the `application.properties` in `src/test/resources` as `application-notexists.properties` and Spring started (but Unit test have errors of Mysql)

Comment: try this dialect.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: H2 accepts this table definition in MySQL compatibility mode, it means you changed some configuration that isn't actually used by unit tests.

Comment: @RaushanKumar I tried but got same error. Added repository to try to clone it.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I'm pretty sure that there are not other configurations. But, please, can you put an eye? I added the repository. Thank you.

Comment: why do you use the database specific `columnDefinition` parameter at all instead of relying on database independent parameters like `length` or `precision` ? Or use Flyway to specifiy the DDL for different engines... From my experience letting JPA create the DB structures always worked very unreliable, latest when it comes to changes in the structure in production.

Comment: @cyberbrain with your indication I solved but... I want to understand why h2 doesn't use instructions. Btw, thank you

Comment: could be the `UNSIGNED` keyword that is not supported by H2 natively (see [INT datatype](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#integer_type) and also not mentioned in the docs of the [compatibility mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility). You could check the compatibilty mode setting [allNumericTypesHavePrecision](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/Mode.html#allNumericTypesHavePrecision)

Comment: H2 accepts and ignores `UNSIGNED` in MySQL compatibility mode. Unit tests in Spring can use an automatic configuration (in that case it needs to be disabled), can use an own properties file in `src/test/resources` (and it can have a custom name like `application-test.properties` or other) and so on. But I'm not familiar with this stack of technologies and cannot say what exactly should be changed here. I can only say that MySQL compatibility mode isn't enabled and it means that specified JDBC URL isn't actually used.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I solved adding

`@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`

to every repository file (see also [How to add the mode=mysql to embedded H2 DB in Spring Boot 1.4.1 for @DataJpaTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364935/how-to-add-the-mode-mysql-to-embedded-h2-db-in-spring-boot-1-4-1-for-datajpates))

Thank to all and every one, also EvgeniJ that pointed me on right direction.