# Running grails with multiple schemas domain on a memory database (HSQLDB or H2)

Tags: hibernate, grails, schema, hsqldb, h2

In my Grails 1.3.7 app I mapped the domain to a legacy oracle database. In this base there are several schemas that I mapped to my domain using GORM. Its complex but it works.

I'm now trying to create an environment that does not depends on the oracle database so the front-end team can run the app from outside the company. They are outsourced. So I've thought in creating a new grails enviroment pointing the datasource to a HSQLDB and setting dbCreate = "create-drop".

I'm havving the following error:

hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - invalid schema name: APR in statement [create table APR.PLATAFORMA]

Every time it tries to create a table on startup.

The problem is that I could not find a way to ask hibernate creates the schemas. I also tried to create the schema programmatically on starup but I had no success. I also tried to use H2 INIT property [Can I have H2 autocreate a schema in an in-memory database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225700/can-i-have-h2-autocreate-a-schema-in-an-in-memory-database) but no success neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the H2 INIT property it should work. What is your database URL, how does the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement look like (did you use `IF EXISTS`?) What is the error message and stack trace in this case?

Comment: this url is working "jdbc:h2:externo;MVCC=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ADM\\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PGIOP"
but if I use the mem database it creates the connection but not the schemas so it will fail when hibernates tries to create the tables. Anyway, after some testes with H2 I found out that grails pior versions to 2.x have a bug with unique constraints what inviabilizes the use of H2. I'm tring now somethink with HSQLDB

Comment: As for the in-memory database, you may need to append `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the database URL, so that the database isn't destroyed when the last connection is closed (as it happens by default).

Answer (score 0):

After creating some bean post processing and hacking HSQLDialect I realised that the best solution was to remove the schema information from the domain.

That ended up that both databases (HSQLDB and H2) had problems with unique constraints. Since my unique constraints were defined in read only classes I did not bother on removing them too.

The app is still working with the oracle database but now I can run it with an in memory database (I'm using HSQLDB) with all tables in the same schema.

Comment: Since you don't have tables with the same name then you don't need to mind with the schema information. Thats my case. But if you do have tables with same names in diferent schemas I don't see other option but to set the schema information in the mapping.