# Schema creation for in-memory database to use in integration tests fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, h2

I intend to write automated test for an application component that reads data from one database, converts and enrichens the data and then stores it in another database. In order to get rid off the external dependencies (the two databases), I'd like to use in-memory databases.

I've reached a point where Hibernate fails to create tables, since the required schemas don't exist (with both H2 and HSQLDB), according to [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225700/can-i-have-h2-autocreate-a-schema-in-an-in-memory-database/5228564#5228564), I can create the required schemas in H2 by appending SQL statements to the connection URL. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working.

You will see two different DataSources defined in my Spring context, I used the MySQL-DataSource to verify that Hibernate actually creates the tables if the database exists (works).

I'm looking forward to any constructive advice and thank you in advance for any effort you put into helping me with this annoying issue!

default-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.oschluet" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- JPA annotations bean post processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Exception translation bean post processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <!-- DATASOURCES FOR EMFS -->
    <bean id="dataSourceMysql" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inmem" />
        <property name="username" value="inmem" />
        <property name="password" value="inmem" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA inmem" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    </bean>

    <!-- EMFS -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oschluet_pu" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="oschluet_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>   
    </persistence-unit>


    <!-- this will be the second PU simulating the "external" database -->
    <persistence-unit name="oschluet_external" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> 
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

My RestController:

```
package de.oschluet.inmem.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import de.oschluet.inmem.entity.User;
import de.oschluet.inmem.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return this.userService.findAll();
    }
}
```

The Stacktrace in the browser (Table User not found):

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:418)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f2ce6ed.findAll(<generated>)
    de.oschluet.inmem.service.UserService.findAll(UserService.java:16)
    de.oschluet.inmem.controller.MyController.findAll(MyController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:328)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao.findAll(UserDao.java:22)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fb3e6c8d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f2ce6ed.findAll(<generated>)
    de.oschluet.inmem.service.UserService.findAll(UserService.java:16)
    de.oschluet.inmem.controller.MyController.findAll(MyController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:328)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao.findAll(UserDao.java:22)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fb3e6c8d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f2ce6ed.findAll(<generated>)
    de.oschluet.inmem.service.UserService.findAll(UserService.java:16)
    de.oschluet.inmem.controller.MyController.findAll(MyController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USER" not found; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.firstname as firstnam2_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname3_0_ from User user0_ [42102-175]
    org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
    org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149)
    org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5071)
    org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1188)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1813)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1921)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1807)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1631)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1619)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:426)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:298)
    org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:270)
    org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:235)
    org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:436)
    org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:379)
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:328)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao.findAll(UserDao.java:22)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fb3e6c8d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    de.oschluet.inmem.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f2ce6ed.findAll(<generated>)
    de.oschluet.inmem.service.UserService.findAll(UserService.java:16)
    de.oschluet.inmem.controller.MyController.findAll(MyController.java:23)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate using something like [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) to create and seed your databases. I've used it in several similar scenarios to this.