# H2 database - how to init multiple schema (yml)

Tags: java, jdbc, yaml, h2

My conf (working):

```
    jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA_1
```

I need to init mulitple schema, but i can't find the syntax. So far I tried:

```
jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA_1, MYSCHEMA_2
jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA_1;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA_2
jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA_1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA_2
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695179/600486

Comment: its not in yml, that looks like what I tried with ';'. But it doesn't work

Comment: @ochi it seems to not work in yml. All examples are in xml or java, and that's not what I want.

Comment: did you try the double-slashes (`\\ `) before the colon (`;`)?

Comment: @ochi the solution as a simple '\' ... got confused by java example, where the double \\ is to escape the first \

Comment: that makes sense..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solution is:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SCHEMA_1\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SCHEMA_2
```

note the simple '\' in yml. Double '\\' in java is to escape the first one.

Comment: That file format is called [YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and the file extension to use for files in that format is [`.yaml`](http://yaml.org/faq.html) when possible. So where does the "yml" come form? I hope you are not running an 8.3 filesystem for your `.jva` programs.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias, me sirvió con los doble \\

Comment: on yaml i must use '\\'  otherwise -> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from (classpath:application-test.yaml)